# XML with Prototype and Moo Tools

Tags: javascript, xml, mootools, prototypejs

Is there any library to handle easily Xml with Prototype or Mootools?

Answer (score 1):

MooTools (not "Moo tools") starting from version 1.3 can handle XML with ease. Even version 1.2 can handle them as long as it's using the new Selector engine (Slick) - you can use Slick with 1.2 by following these instructions: http://gist.github.com/361474